# How to pass | (pipe) as argument to java command in terminal

Tags: java, shell, terminal

I'm trying to run

```
java -jar jarname |
```

where | is the pipe delimiter.

But, what's happening is it's thinking of pipe as another terminal command.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the pipe. In most shells (sh/Bash/…), the following works:

```sh
java -jar jarname '|'
```

or

```sh
java -jar jarname \|
```

Comment: @HimanshuGoyal It *definitely* works, you’ll need to provide more details.